# Beginner C# Good Practices

Tags: c#

I'm just beginning in c# and I made a little program here. I'm just wondering if `goto` is a valid way of returning to certain sections of my code or if there is a more appropriate and practical way of doing it.

```
namespace Section5Tests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Start:
            var number = new Random().Next(1, 10);
            int secret = number;

            Console.WriteLine("Secret Number is between 1 and 10. ");
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Guess the secret number you only have 3                attempts!");
                Middle:
                var guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (guess == secret)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("WoW! You got it! Well done!");
                    goto Playagain;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect! Try again");
                    goto Middle;
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry you lost =(");
            Playagain:
            Console.WriteLine("Try Again? Y/N");
            var answer = Console.ReadLine();

            if (answer.ToLower() == "y")
            {
                goto Start;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thankyou for playing =)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have to ask, you're not ready for GOTO. Don't use it. Use loops, conditions, and functions instead.

Comment: I've been writing code since the mid-1980s and (outside of assembly code) have never written one goto. There is almost always a better way.

Comment: Well feel free to shed some light on those better ways for me

Comment: The truth is that it has little to do with effectiveness and lots to do with preference.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 2):

In C#, a better way of doing things like this would be to refactor the program into individual methods which have unique and descriptive names. This is a much better solution than using `goto` in 99.9% of cases.

You generally never want all of your code to be in a single `main` method. Instead, I would refactor the game itself into its own method. Then, in the main loop, you can only check if the user is playing.

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    var isPlaying = true;
    while (isPlaying)
    {
        isPlaying = PlayGame();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Thankyou for playing =)");
}
```

That way, you can have the `PlayGame` method return a bool to specify if the user is still playing. Instead of using `goto`, you can control the program's flow using check variables and smart coding:

```
static bool PlayGame ()
{
    int number = new Random().Next(1, 10);
    var userWon = false;

    Console.WriteLine("Secret Number is between 1 and 10. ");
    for (var numOfAttempts = 10; numOfAttempts > 0; numOfAttempts--)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Guess the secret number you only have {numOfAttempts} attempts!");

        var guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (guess == number)
        {
            userWon = true;
            break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect! Try again");
    }

    if (userWon)
        Console.WriteLine("WoW! You got it! Well done!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry you lost =(");

    Console.WriteLine("Try Again? Y/N");
    var answer = Console.ReadLine();

    return answer.ToLower() == "y";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to ask, you're not ready for GOTO. Don't use it. Use loops and functions instead.

To get you started, instead of `Start:`, use this:

```
string answer = "y";
while (answer = "y")
{
```

Of course you'll need to close that loop up down near your `goto Start;` statement, but this looks like coursework so I'll stop here. This should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

> wondering if goto is a valid way of **returning** to certain sections
>   of my code

**No**, it **never** is.

Only jumping **forward out of deeply nested loops**  where a `break` won't go far enough, is valid. (And even that is frowned upon by many..)

All other uses are way too hard to understand when reading and debugging the code.

Instead write **meaningful conditions** in your loops! And try to concentrate on **what** you want to achieve, not **how**..

Breaking down your goals top down into small and simple chunks of work will help avoid coming even close to think about *'program flow'* and helps thinking about *'solving problems'* instead.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be a bit different from the other answers. So, I have added if else statements inside your if statements to replace the goto() function. It's a bit of a long way of doing it but I hope it is easy enough to understand.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var number = new Random().Next(1, 10);
    int secret = number;
    bool playAgain = true;

    while (playAgain == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Secret Number is between 1 and 10. ");
        for (var i = 10; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Guess the secret number you only have " + i + " attempts!");
        
            var guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (guess == secret)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("WoW! You got it! Well done!");
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like Play Again ? Y/N");
                var play = Console.ReadLine();
                if (play == "Y")
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    playAgain = false;
                    break;
                }

            }
            else if(i == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry you lost =(");
                Console.WriteLine("Try Again? Y/N");
                var play = Console.ReadLine();

                if (play == "Y")
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thankyou for playing =)");
                    playAgain = false;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```